# Better performance with XPath Axes Vs Location Path Expression in XSLT/Xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

which one give better performance when we handling XML with XSLT

**XPath Axes** (i.e. parent,attribute,child.....) or **Location Path Expression** (i.e. ./.., ./@attribute ,./childnode,... )

Please help me which one is give more performance and safe to use..

Answer (score 3):

They are identical. Most axes can be selected only using the full form, but there are abbreviations for the most common ones that make an XPath expression more concise.

- `child::` may be omitted
- `//` == `descendant-or-self::node()`
- `@` == `attribute::`
- `.` == `self:node()`
- `..` == `parent::node()`

Comment: thanks for reply. they are identical in functionality. same in performance  also??

Comment: They are exactly the same in every respect. XSLT processors treat them as equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Borodin's answer is almost correct.

**While the given expressions have the same efficiency,  their are some subtle differences in the syntax rules of using them**.

For example:

```
.[someCondition]

..[someCondition]
```

**are invalid XPath 1.0 expressions** and any compliant XSLT 1.0 processor raises a compile-time error. These are legal in XPath 2.0.

**In Xpath 1.0 one should use these, syntactically legal expressions:**

```
self::node()[someCondition]

parent::node()[someCondition]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you have performance issues (and it was not only a theoretical question) you should have a look to `<xsl:key..` and `select="key..`. This can speed up transformation a lot depending on requirements and complexity.